# has_many :things, as: :model, dependent: :destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have Lead, a type of user. Im using Single Table Inheritance. A lead has many notes.

```
# A Lead is a type of User that might be interested in using our service.
class Lead < User
  has_many :notes, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :notes,
                                reject_if: proc { |atrs| atrs['info'].blank? }

end

# Used to keep information about a particular lead's behavior.
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :info, presence: true
end
```

The migration looks something like

```
class CreateNotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :notes do |t|
      t.references :lead, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.text :info

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

This was working fine in development using `sqlite3`, but in production using `pg` I get an error like

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "leads" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "notes" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_c82accd29c"
FOREIGN KEY ("lead_id")
  REFERENCES "leads" ("id")

   (0.5ms)  ROLLBACK
rake aborted!
```

So I changed the migration

```
t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
```

And I changed the Lead

```
has_many :notes, as: :user, dependent: :destroy
```

This almost works. But running commands like `@lead.notes.build` or `@lead.destroy` gets me an error like: no such attribute `:user_type` in `:notes`

What's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the migration from

```rb
t.references :lead
```

to

```
t.references :user
```

is correct. However, to keep this whole thing working, you have to specify a foreign key in your association.

```
class Lead < User
  has_many :notes, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: :user_id
  # code
end
```

You might also have to change some validations. For example

```
validates_presence_of :lead_id
```

to

```
validates_presence_of :user_id
```

`pg` should no longer give you errors when deploying.

I know because that's how I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

**The error says there is no table called leads in database**
Is there  a table called leads in database in development mode. Check it.

**If there is table named leads then** check your migration if there exists a migration to create lead table executed first and then migration to create notes.

Comment: I'm using single table inheritance. Leads table is not necessary.